# Could not find or load main class > org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, openfire

Trying to run openfire server on Eclipse.  I meticulously followed the instructions for "[Openfire SVN + Eclipse 3.3 + Subversive Installation Guide](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1020)". Unfortunately I've been hung up at a roadblock for quite sometime now.  I attempt to run openfire and get...

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter

Made a blury video of what I'm seeing here:  http://youtu.be/I8UGp4CZpbo

Any insight, suggestions, help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

3-21-19
Now the console returns:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your source folders to `src/java`, so that the package name is `org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter instead of java.org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter`.